# ROC (Taiwan) residency for nationals and families of nationals

Tags: repatriation, taiwan

Take an ROC-born, naturalized American citizen who hasn't lived in Taiwan for 30+ years. She hasn't renounced ROC citizenship but, by not maintaining household registration, IIUC she no longer has a right of abode in Taiwan. How easy would it be for her to get a permanent residency in Taiwan? What about for her (non-ROC-national) family members?

Comment: "by not maintaining household registration, IIUC she no longer has a right of abode in Taiwan" Are you sure about this? I don't think Taiwan household registration can be lost by moving overseas. I think she just needs to do move in registration if she moves back to Taiwan.

Comment: @user102008 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_without_household_registration

Comment: Where could I find more info about whether household registration status of citizens?

Comment: Right, there are ROC nationals without household registration, but those people never had household registration. She had household registration, and I don't see any place that says she can lose it.

Answer (score 3):

Taiwan's citizenship won't be gone without formal renouncement. It's possible to lose Taiwan citizenship involuntary if the citizen acquires mainland China's(PRC) citizenship. Taiwan's current law does allow dual citizenship unless the citizen works for Taiwan's government.  She can restore the status pretty easily as long as she has the appropriate documents.